# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Due to Duplicate Key Value

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I got the integrity constraint violation error when trying to insert news rows into a database table using the code below.

```
public void ExtractBoard() throws IOException, SQLException {
    int rows = 0;
    String sqlInser = "INSERT INTO APP.SUBSCRIBERBR (subID, boardno)"+"VALUES (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInser, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    String[] AryFiles2 = rf.OpenFile();
    int i,j;
    String p1 = "", p2 = "";
    for (i=0; i<AryFiles2.length; i++) {
        if (AryFiles2[i].contains("ADD VSBR")) {
            String[][] parts = this.LineParts();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(parts[i][0]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
            int intst = in.nextInt();
            p1 = String.valueOf(intst);
            for (j=0; j<parts[1].length; j++) {
               if (parts[i][j].contains("MN")) {
                   Scanner inn = new Scanner(parts[i][j]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
                   int intstr = inn.nextInt();
                   p2 = String.valueOf(intstr); 

               }
           }
       }
       if(p1 != null && p2 != null){
           stmt.setString(1, p1);
           stmt.setString(2,p2);
           rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
       }
       else {
           throw new SQLException("Null parameters");
       }
   }
}
```

This is the error message I am getting.

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL150827011836400' defined on 'SUBSCRIBERBR'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be a bit helpful if You could post the scheme of the database table. But the exception itself already tells you that you try to insert a value into the database as primary key (or at least into a unique column) that already exists. So You also should check the contents of the file that You read the values from.

Answer (score 0):

Your subID variable seems to be duplicated. (there is another record with the same subID in your table)

Possible reasons are:

1. your file reading method is faulty and you end up reading your input file wrong.
2. your input file contains duplicated keys already.
3. everything is ok, but you are trying to run your code against the same database without cleaning it first, so you end up finding records with this subID from your previous run.

Comment: I think the file has duplicate keys. I wanted to get some help on how to add code lines to skip the keys that are already inserted, using sql keyword 'EXISTS' or something.

Comment: First you should verify your assumption. *Then* as a possible solution (since you are aiming for something easy) I would suggest simply catching the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException and skip the offending row.

Comment: It's easier (and cheaper than exception handling) to ask the database, if a key was already written. You can use a simple select, like `select subID from APP.SUBSCRIBERBR where subID = ?`. If you got no rows you can insert.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `p1` or `p2` to null, so if the `if` statement is false on the first iteration, you insert `"", ""`, and if the `if` statement is false in subsequent iterations, you insert the *same* values as the previous iteration did.

Comment: If he would insert the values "", "" he should get a not null constraints violation or a type violation, because `subID` is the primary key with type number/int, I guess.

Comment: @dev.null You're right, but there are so, *so* many things wrong with that code, that I wouldn't even get around to addressing issues with assumptions about things not shown, like the datatype of the columns, until far down the list. I instead chose to focus on the one part of the logic that would guarantee a duplicate error, which is what the question is about, without explicit knowledge of the incoming data. --- Let's see.... Yeah, there *might* be one or maybe two lines of code I don't have an issue with. More if you count the lines with end-braces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you read the wrong int's so you end up with the wrong values and generate duplicate keys, which violates the constraints.

Your primary key comes from `parts[i][0]` (with `i` starts at 0) at line:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(parts[i][0]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
```

But why do you use the same value for your second sql parameter? `p2` is set to `parts[i][j]` at line

```
Scanner inn = new Scanner(parts[i][j]).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
```

(remember: `j` starts with 0, too) see line

```
for (j=0; j<parts[1].length; j++) {
```

So you read `parts[i][0]` twice.

And the second problem could be the upper limit of the for loop variable `j`: you set it to `parts[1].length`. Shouldn't this parts[i].length?

How can you fix it? Have a look at your values `p1` and `p2`, maybe you can log it. Are these the values you expected?
Which constraints do you have? Only primary key or did the `boardno` also have a constraint or an unique index (see error message)?

You can try something like this:

```
try {
   rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
   logger.error("p1="+p1+" p2="+p2+" catched="+e);
}
```

Comment: I'm not reading the same value for both sql parameters. Notice that after
`for (j=0; j<parts[1].length; j++)` 
there's an if statement 
`if (parts[i][j].contains("MN"))`
and I know that in the files that I'm working with, the part that contains the string "MN" is never in the first column (ie parts[i][0]).
I had correct values in the table using other input files.It's just this file that's giving me the error.

Comment: Sorry I can't. Compagny policy.